# lisp : how to remove a string from list of strings?

Tags: lisp

I have a problem with removing strings from a list of string I use this

```
(remove "lol" '("lol" "lol2" "lol")
```

but it returns the same list. What's the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

You're running into the problem of trying to determine equality. I believe `remove` uses `eql` as its default equality tester. Unfortunately, two strings are not `eql` unless they're actually the same object.

Try:

```
`(remove "lol" '("lol" "lol2" "lol") :test #'equal)
```

Alternatively, if you know you will be testing strings, you could pass `string=` as your test function.

Comment: @NabilAmen If works, you should consider accepting the answer.

Comment: You are correct that the default comparison is `eql`, but you should not just believe it but look it up in the hyperspec.  `Eql` is the standard default comparison across the whole language with very few exceptions, by the way.

Comment: @Svante I actually checked if remove said anything specific, but it didn't, so I went with "well, the default is `eql` and it doesn't say otherwise, but...".

Comment: @Vatine: OK, sorry, you actually have to follow two links from the entry for `remove`, "satisfy the test" and "satisfying a two-argument test" to get to chapter 17.2.1, which specifies the general default.

Answer (score 0):

You should close the ')'
So write : (remove "lol" '("lol" "lol2" "lol")**)**

Comment: it's just a taping mistake , the list won't change i dont know why